# Can anyone tell me which cameras populate sub-second EXIF information?

Tags: metadata, exiftool, burst-mode

I see the EXIF standard has a SubsecTimeOriginal field, but the sample photos I've tried looking at don't seem to have populated the field.  Or maybe the tooling I'm using (GIMP, exiftool, PHP's `exif_read_data`) don't support it for some reason?

Can anyone tell me a camera that definitely populates it on JPG (not RAW) images?  A full list would be AMAZING, but I'm assuming no-one will have that!

I know that camera clocks tend not to be set very accurately, with many being out by an hour or even a year, but my use case is still relevant as I'm interested in the relative amount of time between multiple shots from the same camera.

Comment: iPhone and Android phones tend to populate the field you desire. Many Canon DSLRs also. For FujiFilm, don't know about the X-T3/T30, but earlier cameras do *not*. I don't know about others, but I'd *expect* the major ones would be likely to (Nikon, Sony). You can use `exiftool` to check.

Comment: The question was recently asked here. It seems that most recent cameras and smartphones do... The real question is the accuracy/suitability of the data: statistically my 70D seems to take a lot of pictures on the second sharp...

Comment: By "a lot", do you mean "always".  I.e. the field is there but it just populates it with 000 the whole time?

Comment: Or does it maybe only bother to populate it when doing a burst shot?

Comment: "Full list" answers are not a good fit for Stack Exchange. Who will maintain such a list?

Answer (score 3):

Phil Harvey (author of exiftool) keeps a [collection](https://exiftool.org/sample_images.html) of metadata examples from many cameras/scanners/etc.  The files all have the image data stripped away and just include the metadata.  Scanning through my older local copy of that, it shows 196 files (out of over 6,000) that include `SubSecTimeOriginal`.  The list includes Apple, Canon, Kodak, Nikon, Nokia, and Samsung among others.  For the most part, it does seem to be higher end models but the DSLRs usually seem to have it.

I can say for certain that my Nikon 5000/5100 and Canon EOS 60D pictures do have that tag, while my lower end Samsung phone does not.

Comment: I just checked my Nikon D7200 and was surprised to see that it has changing 100ths of a second in the exif for both JPG and raw NEF.